# Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `IO [Int]'

Tags: haskell, types, io, compiler-errors

Can someone please explain what's going on in my function.

```
arrayReader :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
arrayReader arr = do
  item <- readLn
  return $ if item == 0
          then arr
          else arrayReader item:arr
```

But Haskell is not happy with the 6th line:

```
reader.hs:6:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `IO [Int]'
    In the return type of a call of `arrayReader'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `arrayReader item'
    In the expression: arrayReader item : arr
```

Can someone explain what needs to be changed to make this function compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have a precedence error - `arrayReader item:arr` parses as `(arrayReader item):arr`. You need to write `arrayReader (item:arr)`.

Secondly, `arrayReader` produces something of type `IO [Int]`, but in this context `return` takes something of type `[Int]` and produces `IO [Int]`. You need to rearrange your code so that `return` is only called on `arr`, not on the result of `arrayReader`.

Comment: You don't have to use `return` to produce a result - just calling something that produces a result as the "last thing" you do will also return that result to your own caller.

Comment: In other words, don't `return $ if ...` but use `if ...` and `then return arr`.

Comment: `return` is not the same as in other languages. It doesn't mean return this result. It means stick this thing inside the current context type. So in your case it wraps things in `IO`.